# JMeter: Write data in CSV file as rows and columns

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, csv-file

Can someone please help how to write data in CSV file as rows and columns?

I have below code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

// I am extracting all vars.get from XPath

Name = vars.get("AB");
Requests = vars.get("CD");
Errors = vars.get("EF");
trnxs = vars.get("GH");

CSVWriter csvwriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\J METER\\Report\\Report.csv");
String[] row = new String[]{"Name","Requests"};
csvwriter.writeNext(row);
```

I get an error as:

```
> Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of:
> ``import java.io.FileWriter; import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;  DealerName
> = vars.get( . . . '' Encountered ";" 
> 
> Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:
> Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of:
> ``import java.io.FileWriter; import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;  DealerName
> = vars.get( . . . '' Encountered ";
```

Comment: Your errors message doesn't correspond to the code that you've provided . . .

Answer (score 1):

Follow this method to write data in rows and columns:

1. Create a notepad file out of the dat you want to pass in csv format, in this way -

   ```
   Name, Requests, Errors, trnxs
   AB,CD,EF,GH
   ```

   (No space betweeen the lines and no extra lines)
2. Save the file with .csv extension. For ex: requests.csv
3. Add a csv config element in your thread group and load this requests.csv file.
4. Now you are good to go. You can use these values as parameters.

For ex:

```
//code

system.out.println("The errors are: " + ${Errors})

//code
```

But looking at your code, I am getting a feeling that you are either using some variables which aren't compatible with Jmeter or you havent loaded some of the required jar files.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember to download this "opencsv" library and make sure it is somewhere in [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

There are 2 approaches to get more information about your Beanshell script failure:

1. Add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of your Beanshell script. This way you will be able to get a lot of information regarding your script flow in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)
2. Put your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here  
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Error in beanshell", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   This way you will be able to see normal [stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) in *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on Beanshell scripting and troubleshooting.

---

In general I would recommend using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property instead of your flaky approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

import java.lang.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

**//Extract all variables using Regular Expression Extractor**

Name = vars.get("AB");

Requests = vars.get("CD");

Errors = vars.get("EF");

trnxs = vars.get("GH");

log.info("Name is = " +Name );

log.info("Requests is = " +Requests );

log.info("Errors is = " +Errors );

log.info("trnxs is = " +trnxs );

f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/cn0494/Documents/text.csv", true);**//Give your file path**

p = new PrintStream(f); 

this.interpreter.setOut(p); 

p.println(Name+","+Requests+","+Errors+","+trnxs);

f.close();
```